# Getting WordPress database name/username/password with PHP

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I'm writing a WordPress plug-in and need to read the database name, username, and password (In order to do a sql dump).  Is this possible?

Thanks-

Comment: Why not just re-use the current database connection?

Comment: @Pekka- I'm doing a php system() call mysqldump- I need to pass in those variables.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, they are defined in `wp-config.php`

1. Database Name: DB_NAME
2. Database User: DB_USER
3. Database password: DB_PASSWORD
4. Database Host: DB_HOST

They are define. See you wp-config.php in the root directory of Wordpress

Comment: If this is a plugin that you are going to make available publicly or submit to the WP plugin repository I'd suggest not just hard coding a look up for wp-config.php in the root but also look for wp-config one directory above the root [WordPress wp-config Security Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-config.php) See around Line 26 of wp-load.php of how they look up and include the wp-config.php file

Answer (score 5):

Wordpress has some fairly goofy stuff going on throughout its OO code, this isn't the first one I've encountered as we dig deeper into the internals with each successive project at [Moxune](http://moxune.com).  See [WP_User::__set doesn't persist custom fields as it claims](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98159/wp-user-set-doesnt-persist-custom-fields-as-it-claims).

The goofiness I refer to here of course is that something like the table prefix, aka `wpdb::prefix` is a `public` member variable, however things like `dbname`, `dbpassword`, and `dbhost` are `protected` and there are no `public` accessor methods.

I'm sure one of the Wordpress core devs will try to argue some rationale for it, but in the meantime may as well use some good 'ol OO to cope.  My suggestion, a decorator.

```
class SaneDb
{
    private $_oDb;

    public function __construct(wpdb $oDb)
    {
        $this->_oDb = $oDb;
    }

    public function __get($sField)
    {
        if($sField != '_oDb')
            return $this->_oDb->$sField;
    }

    public function __set($sField, $mValue)
    {
        if($sField != '_oDb')
            $this->_oDb->$sField = $mValue;
    }

    public function __call($sMethod, array $aArgs)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->_oDb, $sMethod), $aArgs);
    }

    public function getDbName() { return $this->_oDb->dbname;     }
    public function getDbPass() { return $this->_oDb->dbpassword; }
    public function getDbHost() { return $this->_oDb->dbhost;     }
}
```

Then atop your plugin code (*functions.php*) setup a `global` in similar vein to `wpdb`.

```
global $sanedb;
$sanedb = new SaneDb($wpdb);
```

From there, just use `$sanedb` within your plugin instead of `$wpdb`.

Lastly, getting ahold of the database name et al.

```
$sanedb->getDbName();
```

Comment: To get db username, add this: public function getDbUser() { return $this->_oDb->dbuser; }

Answer (score 1):

This is super simple now. You can create a PHP file and use the following code.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
// We need the WordPress Database Credentials
global $wpdb;
$user = $wpdb->dbuser;
$pass = $wpdb->dbpassword;
$name = $wpdb->dbname;
```

If you need other data just do a print_r on the wpdb variable and you'll see everything inside of there.